# Get Access to OSM data via SKMaps SDK

Tags: ios, skmaps

I have the skobbler SDK loaded and working but I need to get access to the OSM data and do a tag query but I cannot work out a way to access it.  I am trying to determine the "node" or the intersection that is coming up whilst in free drive mode and query its type i.e stop sign etc.  The SDK returns the maxspeed from the current track but uses a dedicated delegate function.

Comment: That is not possible via the Skobbler/Scout SDK for the time being